# Hacking: how to perform buffer overflow attack?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I am stuck on a hacking exercise.

The program shows this when executed:

```
Build your own string!

Usage:
  ./4 length command...

Each command consist of a single character followed by its index.

Example:
  ./4 11 h0 e1 l2 l3 o4 w6 o7 r8 l9 d10
```

How can I perform a buffer overflow attack with command line arguments?

`atoi` converts the string argument str to an integer (type int).

`memset` copies the character c (an unsigned char) to the first n characters of the string pointed to, by the argument str.

Thank you for your insight!

```
#include <alloca.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void usage(const char *argv0) {
        printf("Build your own string!\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("Usage:\n");
        printf("  %s length command...\n", argv0);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Each command consist of a single character followed by its index.\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("Example:\n");
        printf("  %s 11 h0 e1 l2 l3 o4 w6 o7 r8 l9 d10\n", argv0);
        exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        char *buffer;
        unsigned short buffersize, i, index, length;

        if (argc < 2) usage(argv[0]);

        length = atoi(argv[1]);
        if (length <= 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "bad length\n");
                return 1;
        }

        buffersize = length + 1;
        buffer = alloca(buffersize);
        memset(buffer, ' ', buffersize);
        buffer[buffersize - 1] = 0;

        for (i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
                if (strlen(argv[i]) < 2) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "bad command \"%s\"\n", argv[i]);
                        return 1;
                }

                index = atoi(argv[i] + 1);
                if (index >= length) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "bad index in command \"%s\"\n", argv[i]);
                        return 1;
                }

                buffer[index] = argv[i][0];
        }

        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're being downvoted because your question is essentially "do my homework for me". You should ask a specific question about what you don't understand.

Comment: @Adam I don't understand how to perform a buffer overflow by using command line arguments. The code looks pretty secure.

Comment: It's not secure because it writes to a buffer without checking length. It's easy to exploit because that buffer is allocated with `alloca`.

Comment: You got ratted out by another student: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35671279/hacking-challenge-locating-vulnerability-in-the-code

Answer (score 0):

Bufferoverflows from what i know is where you overwrite the buffer memory addresses to execute your code or to simply point to another address the good function! In your script i believe to get to the next level you have to point the memory address to printf("%s\n", buffer);. To do this use gdb to debug the code and overwrite the memory address to however many bit's away the printf function is.  A decent tutoral is http://www.tenouk.com/Bufferoverflowc/Bufferoverflow4.html . But you should read about c programming  and all the vulnerable code in the sourcecode. Which one is printf("im vulnerable");