# Hacking Challenge - locating vulnerability in the code

Tags: c, stack, buffer, overflow

My Friend recently completed a hacking challenge and sent it to me (binary and source). I wanted to ask here before I asked him for tips as I want to do it myself :)

I've been going through it but I am struggling to find the vulnerability.

```
#include <alloca.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void usage(const char *argv0) {
    printf("Build your own string!\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Usage:\n");
    printf("  %s length command...\n", argv0);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Each command consist of a single character followed by it's index.\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Example:\n");
    printf("  %s 11 h0 e1 l2 l3 o4 w6 o7 r8 l9 d10\n", argv0);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *buffer;
    unsigned short buffersize, i, index, length;

    if (argc < 2) usage(argv[0]);

    length = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (length <= 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "bad length\n");
            return 1;
    }

    buffersize = length + 1;
    buffer = alloca(buffersize);
    memset(buffer, ' ', buffersize);
    buffer[buffersize - 1] = 0;

    for (i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
            if (strlen(argv[i]) < 2) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "bad command \"%s\"\n", argv[i]);
                    return 1;
            }

            index = atoi(argv[i] + 1);
            if (index >= length) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "bad index in command \"%s\"\n", argv[i]);
                    return 1;
            }

            buffer[index] = argv[i][0];
    }

    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

I think the vulnerability lies within the short int, and the use of alloca.

Entering `./app 65535 65535` can cause a segfault but I can't actually override anything since buffer will only ever be set to max 65535 or it loops around. This makes me think I can't override the EIP to inject shellcode.

Can anyone help me with where to look at?

Thanks!

Comment: Try inputting the number defined as `USHRT_MAX` in your environment for the first argument,

Comment: @MikeCAT Yeah I tried that, I can get a seg fault but cant override anything of value since the int will just loop around if I set it larger than the max.

Comment: @JDoby, how will you get a segmentation-fault?

Comment: Debugger should be useful to see where the variables and return address are located, and what is the value in `buffer`.

Comment: since `buffersize` and `length` are `unsigned int`: setting `length` to 65535 will cause `buffersize` to be 0, so nothing will be allocated on the stack for `buffer`. However, since `index` is compared to `length`, `buffer[index]` can be used to override the first 64Kb of the stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the vulnerability lies in the fact that you can store a character at any offset in the buffer allocated with `alloca`, but the test is done on `length` rather than `size`. passing arguments of `65535` and `a1` invokes undefined behavior: `size` as value `0` because of arithmetic wraparound if `unsigned short` has 16 bits.

You can try passing a first argument of 65535 and subsequent arguments with increasing offsets, that will poke values beyond the end of `buffer`, possibly overwriting the return address of `main` and causing a crash:

```
myprog 65535 a3 a7 a15 a19 a23 a27 a31 a35 a39 a43 a47 a51 a55 a59 a63 ...
```

Depending on the actual local variable layout, the required offset may be larger than `17`, but should be smaller than `80`.

Comment: Awesome, I actually tried this but didn't enter enough to actually cause a crash! How would I go about entering 'A's for this to override EIP with x414141 as I can only seem to enter offset numbers like you said.

Comment: @JDoby: you would first locate the return address, say 24 and then pass arguments A24 A25 A26 A27... 4 or 8 of them depending on the architecture.  But a single poke into a more significant byte of the return address should suffice, and would be more elegant.