# Overwriting the stored return address on the stack doesn't work

Tags: c, gdb, shellcode

I'm trying to take control of a C program's execution by overwriting the stored return address (`saved eip`) on the stack:

```
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0xbffff550:
 eip = 0x8048831 in main (6.c:52); saved eip = 0xbffffdef
 source language c.
 Arglist at 0xbffff538, args: argc=6, argv=0xbffff5e4
 Locals at 0xbffff538, Previous frame's sp is 0xbffff550
 Saved registers:
  ebx at 0xbffff534, ebp at 0xbffff538, eip at 0xbffff54c
```

The value `0xbffffdef` is the address of a `"Hello, world!"` shellcode which has been assembled, checked for any null bytes and put in an environment variable `SHELLCODE`:

```
(gdb) x/s *((char **)environ + 7)
0xbffffdef: "SHELLCODE=\353\023Y1\300\260\004\061\333C1Ҳ\017̀\260\001K̀\350\350\377\377\377Hello, world!\n\r"
```

Unfortunately the program fails to print the expected greeting:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xbffffdfd in ?? ()
```

Why did it crash and how to solve the problem?

**Notes:**

```
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3.2) 8.1.0.20180409-git
// program was compiled with the following flags:
-m32 -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -fno-PIE -no-pie -g
```

program source: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35671279/3301492)

Comment: Show the source code of the program, please.  Disassembly of the shellcode would be helpful as well.

Comment: Wait a minute, your shellcode is at `0xbffffdef` but you are jumping to `0xffffddef`?  Typo?  Also, what's at `0xbffffdef` is the bytes of the letters `SHELLCODE=` which you don't want to execute, so add 11 to end up with `0xbffffdfa`.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge thank you very much, skipping the `SHELLCODE` (but adding 10, not 11) helped! Should I post a full answer?

Comment: Sure, go ahead.  (Yes, you're right, 10, I miscounted.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to @Nate Eldredge

The reason behind this specific crash is the incorrect return address `0xbffffdef`. The location of the environment variable `SHELLCODE` actually points to the beginning of the string `"SHELLCODE=..."`

```
(gdb) x/s *((char **)environ + 7)
0xbffffdef: "SHELLCODE=\353\023Y1\300\260\004\061\333C1Ҳ\017̀\260\001K̀\350\350\377\377\377Hello, world!\n\r"
```

In order to fix the issue, we have to adjust the address by skipping the first 10 characters and point to the `"\353\023Y1\300..."`:

```
0xbffffdef + 0xa = 0xbffffdf9
```

When overwriting the stored return address with this value `0xbffffdf9`, the program is coerced into greeting the world:

```
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0xbffff550:
 eip = 0x8048831 in main (6.c:52); saved eip = 0xbffffdf9
 source language c.
 Arglist at 0xbffff538, args: argc=6, argv=0xbffff5e4
 Locals at 0xbffff538, Previous frame's sp is 0xbffff550
 Saved registers:
  ebx at 0xbffff534, ebp at 0xbffff538, eip at 0xbffff54c
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
Hello, world!
[Inferior 1 (process 28591) exited normally]
```